# How to suppress compiler warning C4373

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've got a problem with warning 4373, specifically. I wish to disable this specific warning. However, the warning `#pragma` has no effect. First I tried using disable around the offending code, and then suppress, but neither had any effect. I also tried using disable around both derived and base methods, with also no effect. How can I suppress specifically this warning?

Edit: Is there any way to disable this warning *for some specific functions*, rather than globally?

Comment: You can use a compiler switch to disable it (`/Wd4373` from memory).

Comment: Disabling compiler warnings is usually a really bad idea.

Comment: This warning is only a compatibility warning. It's really irrelevant.

Comment: Specifically, it's a warning to tell you that the behavior of the current version of the compiler is different from the behavior of previous, bugged version of the compiler. As long as you're writing new code, that doesn't rely on the previous incorrect behavior, the warning is entirely unnecessary. Avoiding doing things that are "usually a really bad idea", without knowledge of whether or not the reason they're a bad idea applies to the specific case, is usually a really bad idea.

Comment: This warning is still turned on by default in VS2017, which makes no sense IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress the warning locally using [`#pragma`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx).

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4373 )
// Some code
#pragma warning( pop )
```

So, for example, starting with [MSDN's C4373 demonstration program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384874.aspx), here's a modified version that suppresses the warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct Base
{
    virtual void f(int i) {
        printf("base\n");
    }
};

#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4373 )
struct Derived : Base
{
    void f(const int i) {  // C4373
        printf("derived\n");
    }
};
#pragma warning ( pop )

void main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base* p = &d;
    p->f(1);
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be the entire base class?

Comment: Well, it's the derived class not the base. If you just wrap the method then the warning returns. Perhaps it's enough to wrap the class declaration only. I'd do some experimenting if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Your project settings should be able to help you. Go to the projects configuration->C/C++->Advanced and enter 4373 in the 'Disable specific warnings' field.

Note that this setting is only applying for the selected configuration, not globally.